# XLSXWritter num_format to seperate thousand,million,or even billion?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Hi im using XLSXWriter for my excel generator and i would like to create a format for number on the excel , i would like to separate the number by thousand like this ###,###.## , i already use

`format = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'#,##0.00'})`

what i want :
[FORMAT PICT DECIMAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDb5q.png)

but it always show the result like this :

[Fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiYCA.png)

what i want is the value of 1000000 will become like this : 1,000,000.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `format = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'#,##0.00'})` this one is working , in my problem just make sure the data is input on number value , excel will throw error if it detect text value, change your data into int and u r good to go ! Well this one is my bad , didnt check twice.